# in ReactNative is it possible to use dynamic values in input/output ranges of animated value interpolate?

Tags: animation, react-native, react-animated

in React Native i'm trying to create an interpolate like this:

```
const animateImage = {
        transform: [            
            {translateY: animationRange.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [0, imageLocation]                
            })}
        ]
    };
```

where `imageLocation` is a dynamic value (that gets updated by the onLayout of a View)

but it seems to me like the `animateImage` style is created and initialized before `onLayout` is called and so it ignores the dynamic value of `imageLocation` that was updated later on.

is it possible to have the input or output ranges depend on  a value that gets updated dynamically?

Comment: I think that should be possible. I tried something like this before although i did that in my render method.

Comment: ok, my bad.  its totally possible. i just needed to keep the imageLocation in state so that setting it in the state would cause a re-render

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use an animated value as part of the output or input Range though.